# building apk with proguard minifyEnabled true is taking so much time (>12 hours>

Tags: android, android-proguard

I want to make a release build with proguard minifyEnabled but it is taking too much time. The build is still running from yesterday( for almost 15 hours+).

> I have added following proguard rules:

```
-verbose

-optimizationpasses 3

-dontwarn com.androidquery.auth.**

-keep class com.androidquery.auth.**

-keep class com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.0.4

-keep class com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1

-keep class com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1

-keep class com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2

-keep class com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+

-keep class com.yalantis:contextmenu:1.0.7

-keep class com.squareup:otto:1.3.8

-keep class com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0

-keep class com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0

-keep class com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0

-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1

-keep class net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.0-beta.2

-keep class com.android.support.**

-keep class com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0

-keep class com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0

-keep class com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0
```

please help, why it is take so much time ?

Comment: You sure your build is running but halting?

Comment: Try to restart Studio and then start building again. I have faced this issue many times.

Comment: @YuJiaao no i am sure build is running.

Comment: @Addy already did that thrice but still same result.

Comment: building with minifyEnabled false only takes 50 seconds.

Comment: why do you think that it did not halt with proguard?

Comment: @VladMatvienko because there is no proguard warnings. i have added -dontwarn to the packages where it was showing warnings. Everything is working fine , android studio is responsive.

Comment: gradle build runs in separate proces, it does not depend on AndroidStudio process, so you can't say that it didn't halt only because studio is responsive. I still think that build halts with proguard enabled. This way only thing I can suggest is to re-install Android Studio

Comment: @VladMatvienko still same problem.